# How to schedule post-processing callback against QgisTaskManager with access to outputs?

Tags: pyqgis

I am using `QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(task)` to schedule tasks to be run concurrently by QGIS' Task Manager, where `task` is an instance of `QgsProcessingAlgRunnerTask` that does some processing and outputs in-memory layers. How can I register a "callback" (i.e. a function to be run when the Task Manager is done performing all the tasks) that has access to the freshly made in-memory layers so that it can for instance write them all to a file?

I was thinking of something like:

```py
def tasks_finished(path: str, layers: Iterable[QgsVectorLayer]):
    # FIXME: how to get a `layers` argument with the in-memory layers? 
    save_layers(QgsProject.instance(), layers, Path(path))

QgsApplication.taskManager().allTasksFinished.connect(partial(tasks_finished, path))
for task in tasks:
    QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(task)
```